# Cosa significa "mazzetto" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *La ragazza di Bube* di Carlo Cassola ho letto:

> Ma, da un po’ di tempo, non invidiava più né 
>   Liliana, né nessun altra ragazza del paese. Le sembrava, per cominciare, di essere la più bella. Anche se i capelli le stavano ritti sulla testa a **mazzetti**, che non c’era verso di tenerli a posto.

Ho cercato il [significato di "mazzetto" nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mazzetto/) e ho visto che si tratta di un

> piccolo mazzo, o mazzo di elementi minuti

Può riferirsi a un mazzo di fiori, di erbe, di lacci da scarpe, di chiavi, ecc, ma non capisco del tutto bene qual è il suo senso nel brano precedente. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Comment: Probabilmente i capelli le si annodavano in modo da risultare inestricabili. Il mazzetto di capelli altro non sarebbe che il gruppo di capelli legati dal nodo.

Comment: Prendi un po' di fiorellini (le margheritine vanno bene) e radunali in mazzetti da una quindicina. Diciamo dieci mazzetti. Ora tienili dritti tutti insieme e avrai un'immagine di quello che intende Cassola.

Answer (score 1):

Ho trovato un paio di occorrenze risalenti al primo Ottocento (https://books.google.it/books?id=VsdOAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA289&lpg=PA289&dq=mazzetti+di+capelli&source=bl&ots=IxZC_73UTa&sig=ZzsSzTZwyLVf57i4vsu3FLBX4BU&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjtyvK348zMAhUKvBQKHbFGBQkQ6AEIUjAK#v=onepage&q=mazzetti%20di%20capelli&f=false) in cui "*mazzette* di capelli" sta per "*ciocche* di capelli". Credo dunque che la descrizione si riferisca a quei capelli corti e lisci che, per quanti sforzi si facciano, restano dritti sulla testa.